# JQuery multiple AND OR selector

Tags: jquery

I need to select HTML DOM elements with multiple selectors.For example, I would like to select all dom that have classes A or B and classes D or C.

Litteraly :

```
((A OR B) AND (C OR D))
```

How can i do that in JQuery ?

I already tried this with no success:

```
$([.A,.B][.C,.D])
```

Any help ?

Comment: You are basically asking for elements that have any of the 4 lettered classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a compound statement where you get all the items that meet the first criteria then filter that out to just the items that meet the second criteria.  This is a bit more scalable if there are lots of possible permutations.

```
$(".A, .B").filter(".C, .D");
```

Comment: This is a really good answer if you just want a selector. However if you want an if statement wrapped around you could always use the is function. if ($('.a, .b').is('.c, .d')) {alert('matching a or b class that has c or d class');}

Comment: @PhilCook - using `.is()` that way assumes there is only one possible result of interest.  Remember, that jQuery objects are collections and can hold many matching objects so `.is()` would only tell you if at least one of the first set matched the `".C, .D"` selector, it wouldn't tell you which ones or how to operate on the collection of matches.

Answer (score 3):

If it's truly that simply, you could just do the Cartesian product and list each possibility:

```
$('.A.C, .A.D, .B.C, .B.D');
```

Comment: 25 seconds earlier... you win :D

Comment: Halas it's not so simple as that. My exemple has 4 classes, but in my pratical case, i can have more than 10, and added dynamicaly

Answer (score 2):

You possible outcomes are:

- .a.c
- .a.d
- .b.c
- .b.d

hence:

```
$('.a.c, .a.d, .b.c, .b.d')
```